# How to pass in a list of Partys for invocation of a flow from the Node shell

Tags: corda

How to pass in a list of Partys for invocation of a flow from the Node shell?

I had tried multiple ways such as passing in as a string (with multiple ways). Do i need to pass in a Json? or what is the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your question. The syntax for passing in lists of elements in the Corda CRaSH shell is:

`flow start fabFlow parties: ["party1", "party2"]`

The syntax for creating complicated objects can be found [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#creating-an-instance-of-a-class) but in essence is just a simple wrapping with curly braces to provide arguments to appropriate invocation params:

`data class Campaign(val name: String, val target: Int)`

`newCampaign: { name: Roger, target: 1000 }`