# How to pass map parameter in corda flow start command

Tags: corda

`flow start TransactionRecoveryFlow report: {O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US=LedgerSyncFindings(missingAtRequester=[24DC1B1C6D8743988C5F4DE6725C64D4354B713D78F27E60CF03398B32657D57, FD3F0A5D8E03A9E8B79229B8271DCEDA691AE106A99F38E5F9F0408FB1F1BAFA, A997737DC3359FE7F3D15CB06E12EF347DA149328F263D2B35F99DA8F363EFCB], missingAtRequestee=[])}`

I am trying to pass report parameter in flow through command line which is a map of type "Map<Party, LedgerSyncFindings>" . How to pass value to it from command line.

I am getting mutliple syntax errors in output.

`exception: while parsing a flow mapping                      in 'reader', line 1, column 11:                                                                                                                   { report: {O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US=Ledg ...                                                                                                           ^                                                                                                                                expected ',' or '}', but got [                                                                                                                  in 'reader', line 1, column 77:                                                                                                                    ... SyncFindings(missingAtRequester=[24DC1B1C6D8743988C5F4DE6725C64D ...                                                                                                           ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 77] - while parsing a flow mapping                                                                in 'reader', line 1, column 11:                                                                                                                   { report: {O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US=Ledg ...                                                                                                           ^                                                                                                                                expected ',' or '}', but got [                                                                                                                  in 'reader', line 1, column 77:                                                                                                                    ... SyncFindings(missingAtRequester=[24DC1B1C6D8743988C5F4DE6725C64D ...                                                                                                           ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 77] - while parsing a flow mapping                                                                in 'reader', line 1, column 11:                                                                                                                   { report: {O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US=Ledg ...                                                                                                           ^                                                                                                                                expected ',' or '}', but got [                                                                                                                  in 'reader', line 1, column 77:                                                                                                                    ... SyncFindings(missingAtRequester=[24DC1B1C6D8743988C5F4DE6725C64D ...                                                                                                           ^                                                                                                      [errorCode=1eyuahe, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.5/1eyuahe]`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @AlessandroBaffa added syntax errors in the question. I even tried to replace '=' with  ':' but still this format is not correct. If I could know how to pass map in parameter then I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891101/how-to-pass-in-a-list-of-partys-for-invocation-of-a-flow-from-the-node-shell/60891137#60891137), a `list` is passed like this:

```
flow start MyFlow listParam: [value1, value2]
```

Following the above approach, a `map` should be passed like this:

```
flow start MyFlow mapParam: [key1:value1, key2:value2]
```

In your code sample, you're missing the brackets `[ ]` around the map, and the colon `:` between your key/value pairs.

Also, pay attention to how you pass objects in the shell (see [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/shell.html#creating-an-instance-of-a-class)).